# Use one df column to filter another df, multiple filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter df1 based on values in the Version column of df2, and then change the Cost Total to 0 in df1. I want to change Cost of those Version which are there in df2.
df1 is [24867 rows x 63 columns]
df2 is [35 rows x 7 columns]

The code I'm using for filtering and setting value is:

```
        df1.loc[
            (df1['Group'] == "CBSS_cq_....JZJN") &
            (df1['Version – USE'] == df2['Version - USE']),
            df1['Cost Total']] = 0
```

The code is assigning Cost Total to 0 for all the 'Group', it is not filtering on my second condition for Version. giving error:

> raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

note that when I used `.values` :

```
    df1.loc[
            (df1['Group'] == "CBSS_.......KJZJN") &
            (df1['Version – USE'].values == df2['Version'].values),
            df1['Cost Total']] = 0
```

giving me following error:

> block_values = np.empty(block_shape, dtype=dtype)
> ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.

**********the above is sorted with .isin *************

My df2 is the template files which are 24 excel files, each having 3-4 sheets. I have looped through all the files and their sheets.
Index Template files are named like-

AdDape CBS Index Template 6.3.xlsx
AdDape Midlife Index Template 5.3.xlsx

And looks  like below:

[image]

```
print("\nIndex Template Files\n")
os.chdir('path to my \IndexTemplatefiles')
FileList = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
print(FileList)

for fname in FileList:
    excel = pd.ExcelFile(fname)

sheets = pd.ExcelFile(fname).sheet_names  # list of sheets
print(fname)

for sheet in excel.sheet_names:

    df2 = pd.read_excel(excel, sheet_name=sheet)

    df3 = pd.read_excel(CostGroupFile, sheet_name='Sheet2')

    #merging df1 and df2
    df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Version', right_on='Version Market - USE', how='left')

    df1.loc[(
        (df1['Cost Group'] == "CBSS_ron_rt_na_disp_JZJN") &
        (df1['Version'].isin(df2['Version Market - USE'])),
        'Cost Total')] = (df1['Market Spend'] / df1['Sum of Impressions']) * df1['Impressions']

    #deleting extra columns
    df1 = df1.drop(columns=['..all columns that came after merging'])

    df1.to_excel(writer, index=False)
    writer.save()
```

This code is working and updating the Cost total values but as you can see the Cost group I have entered manually, I want that to be dynamic.

If the excel file (Index Template files) name is similar to the df3[filename] and its sheet's name i.e. sheetname of df2 is similar to the df3[Sheetname] then use that corresponding cost group and use in the filter part to filter df1 and update cost total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have an example of your data?

 I'm not sure if this is what you want.. though you could try this

```
df1.loc[df1['Version – USE'].isin(df2['Version - USE']), 'Cost Total'] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! this doesn't give me any error, but it's just filtering on my first condition, not second!

Comment: you could probably do `df1.loc[(df1['Group'] == "CBSS_cq_....JZJN")) & (df1['Version – USE'].isin(df2['Version - USE'])), 'Cost Total'] = 0`

Comment: Yeah that's working now! Thanks!! And now I figured out why it wasn't initially because I am looping through sheets of the excel file. The cost group I have given matched only for the first sheet, and not for other sheets, and so the df didn't hold the changes. When I deleted other sheets and read only first then it works. Can you help me making the cost group read dynamically, I have that Cost group column in my df3?